# Cypher query to find to existing nodes and them related them .?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, cypher

I wanted to know if it is possible to find 2 different nodes say one for 
actor.name =  "Arnold" 
and another say
movie.name = "Terminator" and then related them .

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: So, you're kinda just "throwing it out there," asking for something to be created for you, yet you haven't shown anything of your own. What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you attempting to use the REST API? Cypher? Please edit your question to contain more information, and to show what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, I guess you should first [read the fine manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher.html):

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'Arnold'})--(m:Movie {name:'Terminator'})
RETURN p, m
```

Comment: I am guessing the OP wants to know how to create a relationship between two nodes, not how to find two related nodes. But... as I commented under the question, it's actually unclear what's being asked, so I can be completely wrong about that... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers. Yes I am using the REST API.

I finally did it, turned out my controller wasn't being linked to the repository, hence the command wasn't being executed. Thanks anyway.